# How to add a build step in Teamcity to run rspec test

Tags: rspec, teamcity

I am adding a build step to a project in Teamcity.
I want this step to execute by by rspec test (run it like "rspec /spec/features/feature1_spec.rb") and I want to see if test fails in Teamcity.

**Rake or command line ?**

Which step type should I use - rake or command line?

- If I choose rake step, I don't see where to enter "rspec /path/to/my/test.rb".
- If I choose command line step, I can run the step successfully. But I don't see the test results how rspec usually shows it: the step always shows as successful even the tests inside failed.

How to configure the step to run rspec test?

Answer (score 0):

use type 'Rake' for a build step and specify rake tasks: spec.

So it will run 'rake spec'.